# Couldn't implement scrollable using tailwind in next.js 13

Tags: next.js, scroll, tailwind-css, carousel

I am doing some project in next.js 13. This is the part of my code where I tried to implement scroll bar using tailwind css.

```
  <div className="flex w-[1020px]  p-4 overflow-x-scroll">
    <div
      className={` w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open("https://sagarmathamis.netlify.app/", "_blank")
      }
    >
      <Image src={mis} alt="" layout="fill"></Image>
    </div>
    <div
      className={` w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open("https://revampnewsportal.netlify.app/", "_blank")
      }
    >
      <Image src={newsportal} alt="" layout="fill"></Image>
    </div>
    <div
      className={` w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative `}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open("https://onlinesstores.netlify.app/", "_blank")
      }
    >
      <Image src={onlinestore} alt="" layout="fill"></Image>
    </div>
    <div
      className={` w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open("https://searcheproducts.netlify.app/", "_blank")
      }
    >
      <Image src={searchproduct} alt="" layout="fill"></Image>
    </div>
    <div
      className={`bg-teal-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open(
          "https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshan-ojha-78832a1aa/",
          "_blank"
        )
      }
    ></div>
    <div
      className={`bg-red-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open(
          "https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshan-ojha-78832a1aa/",
          "_blank"
        )
      }
    ></div>
    <div
      className={`bg-green-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open(
          "https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshan-ojha-78832a1aa/",
          "_blank"
        )
      }
    ></div>
    <div
      className={`bg-blue-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center`}
      onClick={() =>
        window.open(
          "https://www.linkedin.com/in/roshan-ojha-78832a1aa/",
          "_blank"
        )
      }
    ></div>
  </div>
```

But scrollbar is not showing. All the element of the div are compacted within the parent (1020px) div as in the picture

[image]

What should I do to make this scrollable? Pleas help.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex children via the `shrink-0` utility class:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div class="flex w-[1020px]  p-4 overflow-x-scroll">
  <div class="w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative shrink-0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; object-fit: cover; color: transparent;" />
  </div>
  <div class="w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative shrink-0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?" alt="" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; object-fit: cover; color: transparent;" />
  </div>
  <div class="w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative shrink-0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?0" alt="" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; object-fit: cover; color: transparent;" />
  </div>
  <div class="w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center relative shrink-0">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300?2" alt="" style="position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; inset: 0px; object-fit: cover; color: transparent;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-teal-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center shrink-0"></div>
  <div class="bg-red-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center shrink-0"></div>
  <div class="bg-green-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center shrink-0"></div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500 w-[300px] h-[300px] self-center shrink-0"></div>
</div>
```